# How do I find a computer's IP address?

Tags: c++, sockets, ip-address

I am writing a program in C++ which uses network sockets. I need to find out what the computer's IP address is, so I can display it to the user. The program must run on Windows and Linux.

I have heard somewhere that a computer can have multiple IP addresses. I want the one that other programs on different computers can use to connect to the computer.

Here is the relevant code I already have (the variables are declared in other places):

```
master = new fd_set;
FD_ZERO(master);
struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

listener = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
memset(my_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof my_addr.sin_zero);

bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof my_addr);

listen(listener, 10);

FD_SET(listener, master);

fdmax = listener;
```

Comment: If you clarify why you need this, better answers will come instead of "you may have many, and it depends ..."

Comment: A computer can have as many "IP" address as adapters you have installed on your machine. These can be physical (multiple NICs), virtual (for virtual networks), or system (localhost).

Comment: Actually, you can bind multiple static IPs to a single NIC. This happens a lot in hosted IIS servers. It's been that way since the NT 4 days... I believe SP 4 or SP5 provided that behavior.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously familiar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122208/get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer (others exist for other languages).

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate. I'd close it if I could.

Answer (score 5):

> I have heard somewhere that a computer
>   can have multiple IP addresses. I want
>   the one that other programs on
>   different computers can use to connect
>   to the computer.

Well... that could be any of them. If a computer has multiple IP addresses it can be accessed on any one of them. Of course one of them could be subject to different firewall rules or they could be on two completely different segments but there's no way to detect any and all of these circumstances.

Comment: This is not true.

One computer A belongs to network 1 and 2, and computer B belongs only on network 2, then computer B must use the IP Address for Computer A that is on network 2.

Comment: How is it not true? You're right, of course, that computer B would have to use the network 2 address, but that's basically reiterating Spencer's point about different network segments. There's simply no way, programmatically, of determining which IP address the end user is going to need.

Comment: @Rob: Whoops you're right, I must have missed that part about different segments.

Comment: To complicate the issue, the machine in question may be behind a router or load balancer that is performing NAT.

Answer (score 5):

I posted a similar question, but on OS X recently. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409418/running-a-socket-server-in-cocoa#409426) that I received was to use either 0.0.0.0 or INADDR_ANY. This will cause your socket to listen on all available addresses, so you don't need to figure out which one is the "right" one.

Comment: Of course if you're on OSX you'll not want to do this, because listening on some of the tunneling sockets are CPU expensive even when idle.  Getaddrinfo() with a specific IP version...

Comment: That's fair. I'm just writing a small app for me, but your point is taken.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, you want to use [GetAdaptersAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915(VS.85).aspx) - this lists all of the adapters in your machine and the IP addresses bound to them. It supports IPv6 addresses too. You can also use [gethostbyname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524.aspx), but that doesn't support IPv6.

On Linux, we read `/proc/net/dev` and `/proc/net/if_inet6` and parse the results of that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use getaddrinfo() with your listener socket, to obtain the IP Address of the socket you bound to.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you're trying to get your LAN IP address (i.e. the address of your computer within the set of your computers) or the IP address your service provider gives to you every time you connect to the internet. The latter can be identified with a query (I guess that you would find a proper C++ library that does that with little Googling) to some IP detecting web services.

If you want a **quick and dirty** solution you could try to wget http://www.whatismyip.org and read back the contents.

Comment: This works if you want the IP address that is seen on the Internet. But unless the computer is Internet facing, this is usually a NAT'ed address handled by a firewall and not actually reflective of the actual IP of the computer system itself.

Comment: You're right, but this somehow falls in the first option I pointed out. In that case you probably want your LAN address since you share your WAN address with other systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [light-weighted client/server socket class in C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/client_server_socket.aspx?fid=49576&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=51) project for reference.