# fetch value of ipaddress

Tags: c, linux

i want to get ipaddress of mycomputer in a variable 
this statement prints ipaddress of my computer 
but i want to assign it in a varible 
how can i fetch the value of ipaddress from `inet_ntoa(inaddrr(ifr_addr.sa_data))` into an variable ip of `char*` type .

```
printf("IP Address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(inaddrr(ifr_addr.sa_data)));
```

Comment: As we pointed out the last three times you asked this, it's a duplicate.  Read the answer we linked to when we closed it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485769/how-do-i-find-a-computers-ip-address

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917332/getting-my-ip-address

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer

Comment: This isn't actually a duplicate of those questions - it's really a more basic C question.

Answer (score 2):

`inet_ntoa` already returns a `char *` - it's just that it points to a static buffer, which will be overwritten on subsequent calls.  If you want to save that pointed-to string, you can just use `strdup()`:

```
char *ip;
/* ... */
ip = strdup(inet_ntoa(inaddrr(ifr_addr.sa_data)));
```

You should call `free()` on `ip` when you are done with it.